# Excel with pivot tables crashes after loading data dynamically thru Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, excel-2016

I'm currently working on a Java application that uses a template excel file that contains a pivot tables.

The template file also has a data sheet that seeds pivot tables. This data sheet is dynamically loaded by java application through the Apache POI (SXSSF*) apis, data sheet contains anywhere between 100K to 1M records. After loading data thru Java application I reload pivot table data thru excel pivot table with auto-refresh option.

If I have anywhere between 100K-300K records my pivot tables are getting refreshed but if I have more then 300K records, during excel file opening, excel crashes/hangs in "reading data..." phase.

I am using excel 2016 for mac.

Comment: Since you mentioned `SXSSF`: [SXSSFWorkbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) defaults to using inline strings instead of a shared strings table. ..., but is also known to produce documents that are incompatible with some clients. So not using shared strings table is useful while writing but while reading the pivot table data it could be not useful since every string content, even if the same as others, will be separate content. Since pivot tables tends to summarize data which are equal labeled, this could lead to problems.

Comment: I see! so if i use XSSFWorkbook/XSSFSheet pivot refresh performance would be much better? here catch is, loading data from my java program needs very large heap in case of XSSF* programs and it takes long time for program execution. Is there any better way?

Comment: You could try SXSSFWorkbook but set `useSharedStringsTable` true in `public SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook,
             int rowAccessWindowSize,
             boolean compressTmpFiles,
             boolean useSharedStringsTable)`

Comment: Tried this option, its still slower for pivot calculations. Is there any option to refresh pivot at the time of file creation time? I believe NO?